# Why does template substitution fail on a constructor unless I add brackets?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am trying to understand why substitution fails on the following snippet unless brackets are added:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct A {};

template<typename T>
struct B {
    B(A<T>);
};

template<typename T>
void example(A<T>, B<T>);

struct C {};

struct D {
    D(C);
};

void example2(C, D);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    example(A<int>{}, A<int>{}); // error
    example(A<int>{}, {A<int>{}}); // ok

    example2(C{}, C{}); // ok
    example2(C{}, {C{}}); // ok

    return 0;
}
```

See this example: https://godbolt.org/z/XPqHww

For `example2` I am able to implicitly pass the `C{}` to the constructor of `D` without any error. For `example` I am not allowed to implicitly pass the `A<int>{}` until I add brackets.

What defines this behaviour?

Comment: Note what clang is telling you: `10:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'B' against 'A'  void example(A<T>, B<T>);`

Comment: But it can match `C` against `D` and use the `D(C)` constructor. They are also different types, so I am still a bit confused.

Comment: After putting the brackets, the compiler can deduce thee template argument but without it it can't and then won't know the right instance of `B` to use its constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`example` is a function template and the function parameters depend on the template parameter. Therefore and since you did not specify any template arguments explicitly in the call `example(A<int>{}, A<int>{});`, when you call this function, *template argument deduction* is performed to figure out what type `T` should be for the call.

With a few exceptions template argument deduction requires that a `T` can be found such that the type of the argument in the function call matches the type in the function parameter *exactly*.

The issue with your call is that `A<int>` does clearly not match  `B<T>` exactly for any `T` (and none of the exceptions apply either), so the call will fail.

This behavior is necessary, because the compiler would otherwise need to test all possible types `T` to check whether the function can be called. That would be computationally infeasible or impossible.

---

In the call `example2(C{}, C{});` no templates are involved, so no template argument deduction is performed. Because the compiler doesn't need to figure out the target type in the parameter anymore, it becomes feasible to consider *implicit conversions* from the known argument type to the known parameter type. One such implicit conversion is the construction of `D` from `C` via the non-explicit constructor `D(C);`. So the call succeeds with that conversion.

`example2(C{}, {C{}});` does effectively the same.

---

The question then is why `example(A<int>{}, {A<int>{}});` works. This is because of a specific rule that can be found e.g. in [[temp.deduct.type]/5.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#5.6) of the C++17 standard (draft N4659). It says that a function argument/parameter pair for which the argument is an *initializer list* (i.e. `{A<int>{}}`) and the parameter is not a specialization of `std::initializer_list` or an array type (it is neither here), the function parameter is a *non-deduced context*.

*Non-deduced context* means that the function argument/parameter pair will *not* be used during template argument deduction to figure out the type of `T`. This means its type does not need to match exactly. Instead, if template argument deduction otherwise succeeds, the resulting `T` will simply be substituted into the non-deduced context and from there implicit conversions will be considered as before. `B<T>` can be constructed from `{A<int>}` if `T = int` because of the non-explicit constructor `B(A<T>);`.

Now the question is whether template argument deduction will succeed and deduce `T = int`. It can only succeed if a `T` can be deduced from another function parameter. And indeed there is still the first parameter, for which the types match exactly: `A<int>`/`A<T>` matches for `T = int` and because this function argument doesn't use an initializer list, it is a context from which `T` will be deduced.

So indeed for `example(A<int>{}, {A<int>{}});` deduction from the first argument will yield `T = int` and substitution into the second parameter `B<T>` makes the initialization/conversion `B<T>{A<int>{}}` succeed, so that the call is viable.

---

If you were to use initializer lists for *both* parameters as in `example({A<int>{}}, {A<int>{}});`, both argument/parameter pairs become non-deduced context and there wouldn't be anything left to deduce `T` from and so the call would fail for failure to deduce `T`.

---

You can make all calls work by specifying `T` explicitly, so that template argument deduction becomes unnecessary, e.g.:

```
example<int>(A<int>{}, A<int>{});
```